# Saving files directory with "forward slash" in a txt file with cmd

Tags: cmd, backslash

as the subject suggest, i need to save some directories of some files from a folder to a txt file getting "forward slash".

**So, i made this .bat with this simple string:**

```
dir *.* /a/b/s > F:/TEST/FilesList.txt
```

i placed in F:/TEST a file called "MEDIA_02.mp4"

**So in the txt i get:**

```
F:\TEST\MEDIA_02.mp4
```

**The result i need to get is: F:/TEST/MEDIA_02.mp4 ( With forward slash ).**

I'm not a programmer but i understand few things, i need to get "forward slash" because i need to read some directories with unrealengine and this does not recognize "backslash" in the path.

Thank you very much for your support guys!

UPDATE: Don't need to do it necessarly through cmd, it could be another language aswell. The goal is to get those directories with forward slash, to get then read by unrealengine.

Comment: The command __DIR__ of the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` does not support what you want as the directory separator is ``\`` on Windows and not `/` as on Linux/Mac as explained by the Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file). So there should be used `dir *.* /a /b /s >F:\TEST\FilesList.txt` (that is the correct syntax on which no automatic corrections must be done by `cmd.exe` and Windows file API functions) and next run a replace on file `F:\TEST\FilesList.txt` to get file names with `/`.

Comment: There could be used also in a batch file (not in a command prompt window) the command line `(for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /A /B /S 2^>nul') do set "FileName=%%I" & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & echo !FileName:\=/!& endlocal)>F:\TEST\FilesList.txt`. PS: I do not believe it that the Unreal engine does not support file names with correct directory separator on Windows. I suppose this is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) description and the real problem is the usage of wrong syntax somewhere else in code of entire task.

Comment: Thank you for the comment Mofi. In Unreal Engine i made a c++ code and some blueprint nodes that make possible to read an array of paths stored in .txt file. Since the path had / it was working pretty good, then i made a .bat file that at each run, it updates the paths stored in the txt file with the new ones, but the .bat prints the path with "\" and Unreal Engine does not recognize anymore these paths because of that.

Comment: I suppose that each backslash in in each file name must be escaped with one more backslash as that is the syntax for C++ strings. That was my thought. So the solution should be `(for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /A /B /S 2^>nul') do set "FileName=%%I" & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & echo !FileName:\=\\!& endlocal)>F:\TEST\FilesList.txt` to have the file and directory names with two backslashes per ``\`` in the text file. I recommend to use `/A-D` instead of just `/A` to exclude directories.

Comment: BTW: If none of the files contain `!` in name. It would be faster to use in the batch file after `@echo off` the command line `setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion` and use `endlocal` at end of the batch file and remove `& setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and `& endlocal` from the __FOR__ command line.

Comment: WORKED!! Thank you very much Mofi!!! THANK YOU!

In your code: 
@echo off
(for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /A /B /S 2^>nul') do set "FileName=%%I" & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & echo !FileName:\=/!& endlocal)>F:\MEDIA_FOR_TEST\FilesList.txt

i replaced !FileName:\=\\ with !FileName:\=/ 

and it gave me exactly what i wanted to get! Now Unreal reads it pretty well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mofi replied with this solution in the comments:

> I suppose that each backslash in in each file name must be escaped
> with one more backslash as that is the syntax for C++ strings. That
> was my thought. So the solution should be `(for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /B /S 2^>nul') do set "FileName=%%I" & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & echo !FileName:\=\\!& endlocal)>F:\TEST\FilesList.txt` to have the file and directory names
> with two backslashes per `\` in the text file. I recommend to use `/A-D`
> instead of just `/A` to exclude directories.

So, the full string is:

```
@echo off
(for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /B /S 2^>nul') do set "FileName=%%I" & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & echo !FileName:\=/!& endlocal)>F:\FilesList.txt
```

**The .bat reads the files in the folder where is located, it takes the paths and save it in a .txt "F:\Fileslist.txt", but instead of saving it with `"\"` it saves it with `"/"`.**

Thank you Mofi again for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to replace the REVERSE SOLIDUS '\' characters with a SOLIDUS '/' before writing the file. If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell is available.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    (Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.*').FullName ^| ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '\\','/'} ^| Out-File './FilesList.txt' -Encoding ascii
```

I note that there is nothing in the question about limiting the output to files and not directories. For `cmd` that would be done with `DIR /A:-D`. If you want only files in PowerShell, use `Get-ChildItem -File -Filter '*.*'` if you are on PowerShell 5.1+.

Comment: Useful this solution too, thank you! For now it will be okay the solution i got in the comments. 
I edited the post with the solution :D

Comment: @GiovanniDeMiccoli, what does `/A` do in the solution? It does not exclude directories. `DIR /?`

Comment: Well, checking back the begin of the command, nothing, so it could be removed. I'll edit the posts.

Comment: The purpose of this is because i have a blueprint node i made in unreal engine that reads paths from a txt file and store it in a variable in the engine. When you try to print a simple .txt file it gives you at the base the "\" , and when unreal tries to read the .txt he won't recognize the path, but now that i can reverse the backslash to "/" it works nice!